# Viewing .EXR file types on a mac?

Tags: macos

Is there any program or way of viewing .EXR files on Mac OS? I tried downloading a few different programs but none of them worked.

Comment: What version of OS X? I forget what version of OS X added built-in support for .exr images (around 10.5 to 10.7 I believe). Most of the sample .exr files I have here can be previewed in the Finder (via QuickLook) and opened in Preview....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Is there any program or way of viewing .EXR files on Mac OS?

Install [openexr](http://www.openexr.com/).

---

#### Install openexr on Mac OSX

> **About the App**
>
> - App name: openexr
> - App description: OpenEXR Graphics Tools (high dynamic-range image file format)
> - App website: http://www.openexr.com/
>
> **Install the App**
>
> 1. Press Command+Space and type Terminal and press enter/return key.
> 2. Run in Terminal app:
>
>    ```
>    ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null
>    ```
>
>    and press enter/return key. Wait for the command to finish.
> 3. Run:
>
>    ```
>    brew install openexr
>    ```
> 4. Done! You can now use openexr.

Source [Install openexr on Mac OSX](http://macappstore.org/openexr/)

Comment: Downloaded the .dmg of that, didn't know i had to use terminal though, awesome thank you !

Comment: My installation appears to have finished `==> Installing openexr
==> Pouring openexr--2.5.5.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/openexr/2.5.5: 152 files, 6.6MB` but I still can't preview .exr files with QuickLook. Only Affinity Photo will open them, but if I don't know what I'm opening in advance it's time-consuming to open one by one. This "OpenEXR Graphics Tools" app... where is it installed now? Anyway, I was hoping a QuickLook plugin would be included with the tools but it is apparently not.

Answer (score 2):

These days you can just open it with Preview. Much easier ;)

Try downloading a sample from here: https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/openexr-images/tree/master/TestImages

You should see it on the finder viewer by pressing space bar, or double click to open directly.

Go to Apps -> Preview -> Open

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).